# SSRS Report not updating in Preview in Visual Studio

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I've never seen this problem before.

The report elements are not updating from changes made in the Design mode in Visual Studio (2015). It's not a data issue - even static text box changes are not appearing.

I had removed the **Member ID** column, combined the **last and first names** into a single **Member Name** column, added a couple of columns and renamed **SEX** to **Gender**. Here's the **Design** view.

[image]

These changes should appear when I click on **Preview** but Visual Studio displays the old report.

[image]

As I mentioned, I haven't seen this before and haven't found any similar issues when using Google-Fu. I have tried restarting VS but that was no help. The only thing I did to get from the first pic to the second is to press the **Preview** button in Visual Studio. I've been trying to make it update for over half an hour now. I've updated and created hundreds of SSRS report over the last 15 years but have never seen or heard of this issue.

Is there some new preview caching that SSRS is now doing? It seems similar to the dumb data caching issue but I don't see where the report would be cached. This is completely ridiculous - what moron would create a caching for something being developed so changes can't be viewed?

How can I see the correct preview in my SSRS report in Viusual Studio?

Comment: Never seen or heard of that and like you I've been doing these things for many years... I take it you tried doing a "Clean Project" from the context menu?

Comment: @AlanSchofield - Actually I didn't try the Clean or Rebuild - I thought it would only work for compiled files. I went back in to give it a try but now it is working (argh) without trying that. Now that I look at it, I think it wasn't updating the file in the **bin\debug folder**. Unfortunately, I didn't think of that at the time. I don't know why it worked now but didn't before - I tried exiting out of VS and restarting but that didn't help before. I supposed I should have taken a video to show that I was just clicking on Preview for future reference.